# When i tried to send mail using phpmailer, i am getting error

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, reactjs

Could not instantiate mail function.
Message couldnot be sentMailer Error: Could not instantiate mail function.

```
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail =new PHPMailer;
$mail->HOST ='localhost';
$mail->PORT = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Username = 'Username';
$mail->Password = 'Pass';
$mail->setFrom('info@zoeticpolymers.com');
$mail->addAddress('nitesh54546@gmail.com','Nitesh');
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@zoeticpolymers.com");
$mail->isHTMl(true);
$mail->Subject = 'PHP Mailer Subject';
$mail->Body = '<h1>You are Welcome Here.....</h1>';
if(!$mail->send()){
    echo 'Message couldnot be sent'; 
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo; die;
}else{
    echo 'Message has been sent'; die;
}
```

Comment: Do you have the SMTP server working? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Mistake: You used HOST as Localhost it's SMTP.mail.com change mail to your server

You are using older version of PHPMailer also let me help you by typing the correct one

You should download from PHPMailer GitHub
Not vendor for this example

````
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                     
    $mail->isSMTP();                                   
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';     //for Gmail               
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;             

    $mail->Username   = 'user@gmail.com';                   
    $mail->Password   = 'your Gmail pass';              


    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port


    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');    


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}```




**Your error was that you used HOST as localhost and older version of PHPMailer.


But use default mail() but change the PHP version to 7.3 since it's better now.**
````

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with **smtp**? The cause of **Could not instantiate mail function** error may be more than one reason. when you try to send large emails and your PHP error log contains the message **Can not send a message: Too big** then your mail transfer agent (Sendmail, postfix, Exim, etc) is refusing to deliver these emails.

The solution is to configure the MTA to allow larger attachments. But this is not always possible. The alternate solution is to use SMTP. You will need access to a SMTP server (and login credentials if your SMTP server requires authentication), consider the given example.

```php
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.example.com";
// used only when SMTP requires authentication  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'smtp_username';
$mail->Password = 'smtp_password';
```

Comment: is your host configured? Try with Gmail once.

Answer (score 0):

If your code looks good, try to install PostFix on your server.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

It worked for me on digital ocean.